# Phoenix Elixir : cannot escape function in elixir compiler

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming, phoenix-framework

From [this tutorial](https://www.viget.com/articles/how-to-redirect-from-the-phoenix-router/), I have some elegant:

```
get("/old-path", Redirector, to: "/new-path")
get("/old-path/:id", Redirector, to: "/new-path?object=:id")
```

in my `router.ex`.

But I now have a more complex case, which requires my redirection to be dynamic. I wanted to go for:

```
get("/other-old-path", Redirector, to: fn conn, options -> "/whatever-path" end)
```

And wrote on my `Redirector` module:

```
to = if is_function(to), do: to.(conn, Keyword.drop(options, :to)), else: to
```

I was pretty confident with my code, but when I tried to execute it, I received the following error:

```
== Compilation error in file web/router.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) cannot escape #Function<5.71083082/2 in :elixir_compiler_10.__MODULE__/1>. The supported values are: lists, tuples, maps, atoms, numbers, bitstrings, PIDs and remote functions in the format &Mod.fun/arity
    (elixir) src/elixir_quote.erl:122: :elixir_quote.argument_error/1
    (elixir) src/elixir_quote.erl:259: :elixir_quote.do_quote/3
    (elixir) src/elixir_quote.erl:310: :elixir_quote.do_escape/3
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router/route.ex:136: Phoenix.Router.Route.build_dispatch/1
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router/route.ex:73: Phoenix.Router.Route.exprs/1
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:334: anonymous fn/1 in Phoenix.Router."MACRO-__before_compile__"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1327: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1327: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (phoenix) expanding macro: Phoenix.Router.__before_compile__/1
    web/router.ex:1: MyApp.Router (module) 
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:208: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

Googling it sent me to [this page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-talk/7FXDKJ_Lpzg) which mentions I can't do what I want to do. I read this has to do with [quoted expressions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/quote-and-unquote.html) so I tried to understand how this can be useful, but still don't.

I tried to pass an anonymous function in a keyword list in a parameter of a function in the console and it worked.

I'm guessing it breaks here because the behavior of `get` is more *meta*.

Anyway, I'm sure I'll get more comfortable along working deeper with Elixir, and one day I'll clearly understand why it did not work (explanations welcome of course!), but by then, how can I write what I want to do?

It doesn't feel like I am doing something elixir-difficult but it apparently is...

Cheers

---

EDIT: thanks for reply.

I did what you suggested @justin-wood but it doesn't work:

```
get("/other-old-path", Redirector, to: &MyApp.Router.do_redirect/2)
```

and at the bottom of the file

```
def do_redirect(conn, options), do: "/youpi"
```

But I get a hideous error:

```
== Compilation error in file web/router.ex ==
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :v3_core.pattern/2    

    The following arguments were given to :v3_core.pattern/2:

        # 1
        {:fun, 0, {:function, {:atom, 0, Vae.Router}, {:atom, 0, :do_redirect}, {:integer, 0, 2}}}

        # 2
        {:core, 2, 0, {:redirector_path, 2}, ... [more uglyness]
```

Comment: `** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :v3_core.pattern/2`  is a compiler bug. Please open up a bug report with a minimal case, including the Elixir and Erlang/OTP versions! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> cannot escape #Function<5.71083082/2 in :elixir_compiler_10.**MODULE**/1>. The supported values are: ... remote functions in the format &Mod.fun/arity

If you use a named function instead of anonymous function, it should work. So in the case of

```
defmodule Foo do
  def bar do
    :baz
  end
end
```

You would use `&Foo.bar/0` to reference the function.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't succeeded, edited my question with the result.

Comment: Exactly! An anonymous function is bound to their current environment and anything that is in the module body (outside of a function) is lost when compilation is done. So if you want to use anonymous functions, they need to apply to a known `&module.fun/arity`.